# Dynamically create view and add to layout and make it editable

Tags: java, android, textview

I have created an activity which has custom textview which can be dragged and dropped on the screen wherever required. I want to add this textview dynamically with the text which is taken from alert dialog to the screen. heres the code of the activty.
As the menu "Add Text" is clicked it will open and alertDialog which will take text from user. now when the user clicks "OK" on alert Dialog, I want to create the `DragView` dynamically on the screen. Please guide me on how can this be achieved.

```
public class DragActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drag);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int ImageId = intent.getIntExtra("drawableId", 0);
        this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).setBackgroundResource(ImageId);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.drag, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_addText:
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            alert.setTitle("Add text");
            alert.setMessage("Please enter text to be displayed on image");

            // Set an EditText view to get user input 
            final EditText input = new EditText(this);
            alert.setView(input);

            alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
              String value = input.getText().toString();

              }
            });

            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                // Canceled.
              }
            });

            alert.show();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
            finish();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }



}
```

And the custom textview code.

```
public class DragView extends TextView {

    private float mLastTouchX;
    private float mLastTouchY;

    private float mDeltaX;
    private float mDeltaY;

    public DragView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public DragView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setText("This is the text");
        setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        setTextSize(20);

        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                final int action = event.getAction();

                mLastTouchX = event.getRawX();
                mLastTouchY = event.getRawY();

                switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
                    mDeltaX = mLastTouchX - lParams.leftMargin;
                    mDeltaY = mLastTouchY - lParams.topMargin;

                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                    mLastTouchX = event.getRawX();
                    mLastTouchY = event.getRawY();

                    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
                    params.leftMargin = (int) (mLastTouchX - mDeltaX);
                    params.topMargin = (int) (mLastTouchY - mDeltaY);
                    setLayoutParams(params);

                    break;
                }
                }
                invalidate();

                return true;
            }
        });

        setOnLongClickListener( new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                setText("The text is changed");
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

XML file-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DragActivity" >

    <com.example.dragview.DragView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        />

     <com.example.dragview.DragView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
         android:ems="10" >

         <requestFocus />
     </com.example.dragview.DragView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it by the following code.

```
alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {
                            String value = input.getText().toString();
                            final DragView textView = new DragView(
                                    getApplicationContext());
                            textView.setText(value);
                            textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                            final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                            textView.setLayoutParams(params);
                            relativeLayout.addView(textView, params);
                        }
                    });

            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {
                            // Canceled.
                        }
                    });

            alert.show();
            return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Simple Idea to do this,using Hashmap

Take one hashset and put all the view through key.like

```
 HashMap<String, View> lay = new HashMap<String, View>();
```

and put view in that hashmap

```
 lay.put("textview", title);
```

Whenever you want to get it get it through Hashmap key

```
 View v = hashMap1.get("textview");
```